# Angular io (4) *ngFor first and last

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-template

I am trying to tell whether an item in an `*ngFor` is the first or last element to style a container. Is there a way to do something like this?

```
<md-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of items" *ngClass="{ 'first' : item.isFirst }">
  <content></content>
</md-expansion-panel>
```

Thanks for any help offered!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Inside the `ngFor` you have access to several variables:

- index: number: The index of the current item in the iterable.
- first: boolean: True when the item is the first item in the iterable.
- last: boolean: True when the item is the last item in the iterable.
- even: boolean: True when the item has an even index in the iterable.
- odd: boolean: True when the item has an odd index in the iterable.

So:

```
<md-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of items; first as isFirst"
    *ngClass="{ 'first' : isFirst }">
  <content></content>
</md-expansion-panel>
```

Documentation at https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf gives this example:

```
<li *ngFor="let user of userObservable | async as users; index as i; first as isFirst">
   {{i}}/{{users.length}}. {{user}} <span *ngIf="isFirst">default</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 27):

This how you can do it :

```
<md-expansion-panel 
    *ngFor="let item of items; let first = first; let last = last" 
    [ngClass]="{ 'first' : first }">
    <content></content>
</md-expansion-panel>
```

NgFor provides several exported values that can be aliased to local variables:

- `index` will be set to the current loop iteration for each template
  context so it start from 0.
- `first` will be set to a boolean value indicating whether the item is
  the first one in the iteration.
- `last` will be set to a boolean value indicating whether the item is
  the last one in the iteration.
- `even` will be set to a boolean value indicating whether this item has
  an even index.
- `odd` will be set to a boolean value indicating whether this item has
  an odd index.

for more information  : [**NgFor-directive**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

*a complete example*

```js
<div
    *ngFor="let n of items; let itemsCount = count;let idx = index , let isOdd = odd;let first = first ;let last = last;">
    {{n}} ,
    {{itemsCount}} ,
    {{idx}} ,
    odd  {{isOdd}} ,
    first  {{first}} ,
    last  {{last}}
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-local-variables)

Comment: I am glad I googled. To be honest, I didn't even know these exists, such as `last`, `first` etc. Thank you, you are star!