# How to control special characters at the end of a ngFor

Tags: html, angular

I'm doing a website where I have to present the specialties of a chef, the data was collected from the backend and I present them with an ngFor in the following way:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of item.specialty">
 <p  style="display: inline-block;"> {{i.name}}, &nbsp; </p>
</div>
```

As you see add a comma to show the different specialties followed by a comma, the problem is that the last element is also added a comma, How can I control so that the comma does not appear in the last element that brings the ngFor?

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)? There's a local variable that tells you when you're on the last item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular io (4) \*ngFor first and last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930242/angular-io-4-ngfor-first-and-last)

Comment: yes, if you mean the variable "last", but I dont know how to use this case

Comment: Well what did you try, and what exactly is the problem with it? The code you've posted doesn't even seem to attempt to access it, much less use it to implement what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code  `last` of `*ngFor` it has different properties like `index, first, last, even, odd`

```
<div *ngFor="let i of item.specialty; let last = last;">
 <p  style="display: inline-block;"> {{i.name}}
     <span *ngIf="!last">, &nbsp;</span>
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: in that way, this response does not work, but changing the condition to:
last! == true if it works. Thaks for answer :)