# Apply component style to its last occurrence in a page

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a custom component and it's formatting itself using the accompanying style file. In the containing component, I generate a series of the custom ones. I'd like the last element to have a slightly different style but I'd prefer to control it from within the component itself. Is it possible at all?

I asked this question earlier but got answers based on direct application of CSS while I'm looking for an Angular component encapsulating the style.

The closest I got was applying `:host(:last-child)` but didn't really got it working.

```
div.lower{ border-top: 1px solid gold; ... }
div.lower:host(:last-child){ border-top: 1px solid olive; ... }
```

I prepared a [Blitzy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1jsau) to laborate with. The aim is to make the last element not to have a golden divider in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `div` is a descendant of the component host element, you can use the following selectors:

```
:host(:last-child) div.lower      // Applies the style on the last component instance
:host:not(:last-child) div.lower  // Applies the style except on the last component instance
```

To avoid the golden separator on the last component instance, try these styles:

```
div.lower {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 300px;
}

:host:not(:last-child) div.lower {
  border-top: 1px solid gold;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-seyxvj?file=src/app/custom-thing.css) for a demo.

Comment: Well, there you see. It was almost right except for my ignorance regarding the usage of pseudo-classes (which, frankly speaking, still freak me out a bit after 12 years of web development). I can use them but as soon as it comes to a bit of non-standard thingies, I have bad luck while thinking.   :)